# Can I set the Diagnostic connection string for Windows Azure WebRole from code?

Tags: azure

We are hosting 3party sites in our webrole and to limit them access to the storage container I need to set the connection string from code instead of the connection string in serviceconfiguration?

Is this possible?

Based on answer i ran into a problem.

```
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration dmConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
        DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithConnectionString(conn, dmConfig);
```

This resets the configuration to defaults and overrides the stuff that was deployed with the cloud service. I assume when using the StartWithConnectionString, you cant use the support they added in visual studio for setting these things.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand this statement `This resets the configuration to defaults and overrides the stuff that was deployed with the cloud service.`. Will you please explain?

Comment: If there are a diagnostics settings in storage, it overrides it. But thats properly by design. I figured out how I could read the current configuration and use that.

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen You write: "I figured out how I could read the current configuration and use that" - if possible, could you please share how you did that? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, its a few years and in my old job so cant check the code how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think you can. Do take a look at [`DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.diagnostics.diagnosticmonitor.startwithconnectionstring.aspx) method. You would do something like this in your WebRole's `OnStart()` method:

```
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration dmConfig = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
        DiagnosticMonitor.StartWithConnectionString("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=accountname;AccountKey=accountkey", dmConfig);
        return base.OnStart();
```

However I would not recommend hard coding the connection string in the code itself. Instead take it from some database.

Comment: Np, i have the connection string in RoleSettings. Its just encoded :) And using this approach, can i leave the diagnostic connection string setting empty in code? Could I possible add the encoded connection string in the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString setting and read it from there and decode it and then StartWithConnectionString? (I ask because i read somewhere that the diagnostics are actually started beforethe OnStart). I will test this if you dont know it.

Comment: Aah I see. For some reason I thought something else. I think it should be doable. You could encrypt the connection string and before calling `DiagnosticsMonitor.StartWithConnectionString` you could just decrypt it and pass it to the function.